# Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference when getting saved fragment instance in onCreate

Tags: android, performance, android-fragments

I have created an Activity and using FragmentStatePagerAdapter with 2 fragments.

On onSaveInstanceState, i am saving both the fragments.

```
@Override
protected void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    try {
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,
                BirthDetailInputFragment.class.getName(),
                birthDetailInputFragment);
        getSupportFragmentManager().putFragment(outState,
                SearchBirthDetailsFragment.class.getName(),
                searchBirthDetailsFragment);
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);
}
```

So that i can get the saved instance in onCreate() like below.

```
if (savedInstanceState != null) {
        try {

            birthDetailInputFragment = (BirthDetailInputFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .getFragment(savedInstanceState,
                            BirthDetailInputFragment.class.getName());
            searchBirthDetailsFragment = (SearchBirthDetailsFragment) getSupportFragmentManager()
                    .getFragment(savedInstanceState,
                            SearchBirthDetailsFragment.class.getName());
        } catch (Exception e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    } else {
        searchBirthDetailsFragment = new SearchBirthDetailsFragment();
        birthDetailInputFragment = new BirthDetailInputFragment();
    }
```

But when i change the orientation it gives me below exception 
***java.lang.NullPointerException: Attempt to invoke virtual method 'int java.util.ArrayList.size()' on a null object reference*** in above catch block.

Any guidance would be appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

save data in onSaveInstanceState.
and restore data in onRestoreInstanceState - not oncreate();

Comment: onRestoreInstanceState give me blow error-    e = {IllegalStateException@7870} "java.lang.IllegalStateException: Fragment no longer exists for key com.ojassoft.astrosage.ui.fragments.BirthDetailInputFragment: index 1" "Fragment no longer exists for key com.ojassoft.astrosage.ui.fragments.BirthDetailInputFragment: index 1"

Comment: @TieuNhi - can you explain it?